# how to find whether 2 fields are equal in same column

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Table1
id     REQNo  Qty
D10   RD780  10
D1A   RD786  20
D20   RD34   30
D2A   RD34   40
```

There are two equal substring of (1,2) (i.e) D1 and D2

For D1, if RD780 not equal to RD786 then Qty will be same

For D2, since has same RD34 then sum(Qty) is 70

Required output

```
id   ReqNo    Qty
D10   RD780  10
D1A   RD786  20
D20   RD34   70
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #t(id varchar(10),reg varchar(10),qty int)
insert into #t values('D10','RD780',10),
('D1A','RD786',20),
('D20','RD34',30),
('D2A','RD34',40)

select min(id),reg,sum(qty) from #t group by reg
```

## [See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15153)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
declare @t table (id char(3),REQNo varchar(5),Qty int)
insert into @t(id,REQNo,Qty) values
('D10','RD780',10),
('D1A','RD786',20),
('D20','RD34', 30),
('D2A','RD34', 40)

select MIN(id) as id,REQNo,SUM(Qty) as Qty
from @t
group by SUBSTRING(REQNo,1,2),REQNo
```

Which works by the fact that the `MIN(id)` will be the same as `id` for groups that end up containing only one row.

```
id   REQNo Qty
---- ----- -----------
D20  RD34  70
D10  RD780 10
D1A  RD786 20
```

Comment: whats reason for ...`group by substring()` why not jus `...group by regno`?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi - because the OP seemed to be talking about matching up rows based on `D1` and `D2` which were the first two characters of that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) , First_name, Last_Name, Mobile, Mobile1, Company, Job_title, Tel, Fax, Email, Email1, Country 
from dbo.Visitors 
where (your where statement) GROUP BY First_name, Last_Name, Mobile, Mobile1, Company, Job_title, Website, Tel, Fax, Email, Email1, Country 
HAVING COUNT (*)>1
```